# Grant permissions

Tags: api, permissions, drupal-7

I'm trying to make simple drupal 7 module which after enable adds new role and grants permissions to it. I'm trying to work with Permissions API but it's not working.

```
function mymodule_enable() {

$demo_role = new stdClass();
$demo_role->name = 'demo';
user_role_save($demo_role);

$permissions = array('edit page content');
permissions_grant_permissions('demo', $permissions);
}
```

This only makes a new role but doesn't grant permissions. According to [this](http://drupal.org/node/802272) I don't see the problem.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drupal 7 way to give permission for specific DRUPAL USER ROLE ID.

```
user_role_change_permissions(DRUPAL_ROLe_RID, array(
    'your permission name goes here' => true,
));
```